# Custom FxCop rules to check attributes in MVC application

Tags: fxcop, fxcop-customrules

Is there a reasonably simple way to get FxCop to check whether there is any usage of ViewBag, ViewData in MVC application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very simplest approach would be to screen for MemberBinding instances with the name "ViewBag" or "ViewData" (with `get_` and `set_` prefixes).  This may lead to quite a few false positives, so the next level of complexity/completeness would be to check the type of the MemberBinding target to see if it's a view or controller.  e.g.:

```
private readonly string[] _forbiddenNames = new string[] { "get_ViewBag", "set_ViewBag", "get_ViewData", "set_ViewData" };

public override ProblemCollection Check(Member member)
{
    var method = member as Method;
    if (method != null)
    {
        this.Visit(method.Body);
    }

    return this.Problems;
}

public override void VisitMemberBinding(MemberBinding memberBinding)
{
    base.VisitMemberBinding(memberBinding);

    var memberName = memberBinding.BoundMember.Name.Name;
    if (this._forbiddenNames.Contains(memberName))
    {
        this.Problems.Add(new Problem(this.GetResolution(memberBinding.BoundMember), memberBinding, memberName));
    }
}
```

Comment: HI Nicole, The  code in declared under HomeController public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";
            this.ViewData["temp"] = "WelCome";

            
            
            return View();
        } I tried overriding VisitMethodCall so that i can access MemberBinding instance..but i observed that Visitmethod call is not getting called.How to screen the MemberBinding instance and check for ViewData.Is there any method to parse the memberbinding instances

Comment: The Visit___ overrides won't be called unless you trigger visiting in your Check override.  I've added an example to my answer.